How to iterate over nested alist in emacs lisp?
I want to iterate over this my-list.
How to do it?
(setq my-list '[((a . 1) (b . 2))  ((c . 3))])
(loop for k in my-list do
  (cl-loop for (i . j) in k do
         (message "%c %d" i j)
)

I tried this but failed. error message is "symbol's value is void k."

This code works:
(let ((my-list [((a . 1) (b . 2)) ((c . 3))]))
    (cl-loop for k across my-list do
        (cl-loop for (i . j) in k do
            (message "%s %d" i j))))

(my-list is a vector of lists, not a list)
Some tips to keep in mind:

Literal Vectors vs. Lists: When declaring a literal vector, use square brackets [] without quotation:
(equal '[1 2 3] [1 2 3])
;; => t

When using cl-loop, use the across keyword for vectors, not in:
(cl-loop for k across my-list do ...)

Lisp symbols vs. characters: In Lisp, symbols are different from characters. If you want to use characters (like the char type in C), use the ? notation:
(message "%c" ?A)
;; => A


So, your vector should look like this:
(setq my-list [((?a . 1) (?b . 2)) ((?c . 3))])

When printing Lisp symbols, use the %s format specification:
(message "%s" 'hello)
;; => hello


Lisp Symbols as Variables and Values: Lisp symbols can be used both as variable names and as values. For example:

(setq my-var 'other-symbol)
(setq other-symbol 1)
(symbol-value my-var)
;; => 1



is there no way to sort '[] without changing it to '() ?

You can of course use an array of lists, instead of list of lists, but in that case you have to use functions that work on arrays. @BadEnglish gave you a really good answer. Here is an alternative to cl-loop that resembles @Bretts answer but with your array instead:
(let ((my-list [((a . 1) (b . 2))  ((c . 3))]))
  (dotimes (i (length my-list))
    (dolist (elt (aref my-list i))
      (message "%S" elt))))

I posted as a comment first, but seems like one can't have formatted code in comments, so I made it an answer instead.

Try using the dolist macro, as follows:
(setq my-list '(((a . 1) (b . 2)) ((c . 3))))

(dolist (entry my-list)
  (dolist (pair entry)
    (message "Key: %s, Value: %s" (car pair) (cdr pair))))


is there no way to sort '[] without changing it to '() ?
